# Good counters to AoE comps?

Tags: league-of-legends

If the enemy team is running a large amount of AoE (ex. kennen and morg, vlad and kennen, graves and sona), how do you counter?

Answer (score 7):

To counter an AOE comp, you must prey on their weakness of **needing** to teamfight.

If you run a split-push comp (see: Nidalee, Shen) or a poke comp (see: Kog'Maw, Xerath, Trundle) which both whittle down the opposing team without an actual 5v5, you completely shut down the main objective of an AOE comp.

If the above is not possible for some reason, champions that have good disengages are always a good option.  The number 1 disengager in the game is of course, Janna.  AOE knockbacks are incredibly effective in stopping champions like Kennen and Galio (see: Tristana, Lee Sin, Alistar).

Comment: Wanted to add that its also very good to stay spread out so they can't catch your entire team in a barrage of aoe spells. Also after they have initiated you can usually counter attack very easily because of the long cooldowns on aoe spells.

Answer (score 2):

A poke composition really helps counter aoe fests. Only ever initiate when the enemy are at a very low health from all of the harass you have given. You will always want one champ specifically picked to counter the AoE if you do get engaged.

Examples are:

Pick one champ like that can break initiates:

Trundle, Anivia, Janna, Lee sin.

Then poke champs.

Nidalee, Ezreal, Ahri etc. You know the score.

Answer (score 0):

Any champ that pushes the enemy champs away like: Alistar, Janna, and Lee Sin are good AOE counters.

Comment: Care to explain why you'd consider pushing them away useful? You can often only push one away, which leaves 4 others to kill you

Answer (score 0):

If you see a team starting to pick for an AoE comp, grab Janna as fast as you can; she can pretty much reset the fight with her Ult. Morg and Kennen coming in with their Ults? Have Janna press R and - bam - fight is reset with Morg and Kennen's Ults are down.

As others have said, the Poke comp works well because it keeps you away from them. They will have to hard initiate onto your team and if you have Janna as I said before she can reset the fight. And your team can go back to poking them down.